# PHP: Get value from multi array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to retrieve a value from an Array. Here is the code:

I have array like:

```
$video_categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'videos_cat', ', ' );
```

when print it the result:

```
Array
    (
        [22] => stdClass Object
            (
                [term_id] => 22
                [name] => فيديو
                [slug] => videos
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 47
                [taxonomy] => videos_cat
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 383
                [object_id] => 26138
                [filter] => raw
            ),
        [23] => stdClass Object
            (
                [term_id] => 23
                [name] => العاب
                [slug] => videos
                [term_group] => 0
                [term_taxonomy_id] => 47
                [taxonomy] => videos_cat
                [description] => 
                [parent] => 0
                [count] => 383
                [object_id] => 26138
                [filter] => raw
            )

    )
```

How can I get the value of `term_id` in variable to print it?

Comment: Today there were already 2 question which asked how to access an array an a object! Please learn the basics and read the manual, it's not too hard and the manual also doesn't bite!

Answer (score 1):

Access the index of the array as normal `array[index]`. This contains an object, so you need to use object operator to access it's properties and methods like `object->property` or `object->method()`.

From what it seems your are doing, it'd be something like:

```
echo $categories[22]->term_id;
```

Comment: I was assuming you knew which index you're looking for. You can easily loop over the array to find the properties of each object.

Comment: `foreach (array as $index => $value) { echo "{$value->term_id} for index {$index}"; }` would echo it. I am just trying to explain how, I don't know your specific usage.